# How do I save twitch api image url to png file in a local directory?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

Recently I've been working on a custom twitch chat widget for my stream and I've come across a few issues I need to address first.

Here is the code:

```
var userName = obj.user;
    $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + userName,
headers: {
  'Client-ID': 'ql93k2lg41xsnebz7kgyfjsrg28j532'
},
success: function(data1) {
  var userLogo = data1.logo;
  if (userLogo === null) {
  userLogo = "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/xarth/404_user_70x70.png";
  $("#logo").prepend("<div id='logo' class='image'>" + "<img src='" + userLogo + "' style='width:40px;height:40px;'>" + "</div>");
  } else {
  $("#logo").prepend("<div id='logo' class='image'>" + "<img src='" + userLogo + "' style='width:40px;height:40px;'>" + "</div>");
  }
}});
```

As you can see the script grabs the username from `obj.user` to create the api url link for each user. Then we pull the logo from the users api.

If logo returns null then we set it to the default image link. Otherwise we pull the url from the user api for their logo and display it on screen.

Now I want to take these urls and have them save to my projects directory as .png's as they are loaded for the first time. This way if we have the image already on hand we can call it from our own personal database instead of constantly calling for it from the twitch api.

How could I edit my script to add a function to check if the .png is in directory, then if not pull it from the api call and save a copy to directory for future use in overlays?

It would also have to name the .png's after each user it's pulling from.

Comment: What server-side language are you wanting to use to accomplish this? PHP?

Comment: running through local host from html, css and javascript with a little of ajax as for the program running the entire project i'm not sure cause its not open source so i can only edit html and css documents to add functions to it.